# how to make a vector of x from 1 to max value

Tags: r

In a dataset like this one

[image]

what code should I use if I want to make a vector of

```
x <- 1: max (day)/ID
```

? So `x` will be

```
           1:7 for B1 
           1:11 for B2 
           1:22 for B3
```

I tried

```
max_day <- summaryBy(day ~ ID , df ,FUN=max) # to extract the maximum day per ID
df<- merge (df, max_day) ## to create another column with the maximum day

 max_day<- unique(df[,c("ID", " day.max")]) ## to have one value (max) per ID

##& Finlay the vector
 x <-  1: (max_day$day.max)
```

I got this message

> ```
> Warning message:    
> In 1:(max_day$day.max) :
>    numerical expression has 11134 elements: only the first used
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read How to Ask and the `r` tag description. Screenshots are inappropriate for sharing data. The `r` tag description specifies `dput()` for the sharing of data in a MCVE.

Comment: What is your expected final output?

Comment: when merging with ID x should be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tapply(df$day, df$ID, function(x) 1:max(x))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how should look your output, but you can try this:

```
my_data <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("B1", 3), rep("B2", 4), rep("B3", 3)), 
    day = sample(1:20, 10, replace = TRUE))

tmp <- aggregate(test$day, by = list(test$ID), FUN = max)
sapply(1:nrow(tmp), function(y) return(1:tmp$x[y]))

# [[1]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

# [[2]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

# [[3]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: Why is that 1:19, 1:11, and 1:11 instead of 1:7, 1:11, and 1:22?

Comment: I've applied my solution to some random data to show how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` to loop over unique element of `ID` and generate a sequence from 1 to the `max` for that `ID` in the `day` column

```
sapply(unique(df$ID), function(x) seq(1, max(df[df$ID == x, "day"])))

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

#[[2]]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

#[[3]]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
```

If we want all as one vector , we can try `unlist`

```
unlist(sapply(unique(df$ID), function(x) seq(1, max(df[df$ID == x, "day"]))))

#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#   11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option, using Hadley Wickham's `purrr` package, as part of the tidyverse.

```
d <- data.frame(id = rep(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), c(3, 4, 5)),
            v = c(1:3, 1:4, 1:5),
            day = c(1, 3, 7, 1, 5, 9, 11, 3, 5, 11, 20, 22),
            number = c(15, 20, 30, 25, 26, 28, 35, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18))

library(purrr)

d %>%
    split(.$id) %>% 
    map(~1:max(.$day))

# $B1
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

# $B2
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

# $B3
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <-
data.frame(ID       = c(rep("B1",3),rep("B2",4),rep("B3",5)),
             V      = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),
             day    = c(1,3,7,1,5,9,11,3,5,11,20,22),
             number = c(15,20,30,25,26,28,35,10,12,14,16,18))

x <- list()
n <- 1
for(i in unique(df$ID)){
  max_day <- max(df$day[df$ID==i])
  x[[n]]  <- 1:max_day
  n       <- n+1
}
x
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> [[2]]
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
>
> [[3]]
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
> ```